# Change UIWebView Done button color

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to display content in an app and would like to change the color of the **Done** button that is displayed whenever a select control is used.

It is currently displaying as white on gray which is hard to see.

[image: Picker]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Done" button is white because you are probably setting the `tintColor` to white for all `UIBarButtonItems` using `UIAppearance`. That affects the "Done" Button in the picker view which also happens to be a `UIBarButtonItem`.

So you have to exclude the "Done" button in the picker view from the global white tintColor. I don't know if you only need the white `UIBarButtonItems` in your navigation bar, but if you do you could do this to only set the `tintColor` for the bar button items in your navigation bar and leave all other `UIBarButtonItems` untouched:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

However this is only available in iOS9 and the old `appearanceWhenContainedIn` method that works for older iOS versions is not available in Swift.

So, if you are working with Swift and you have to target earlier iOS versions than iOS9 this is probably not working for you. In that case you have to remove the `UIAppearance` setting for the white `tintColor` and set the `tintColor` for the `UIBarButtonItems` in your navigation bar "manually" without using `UIAppearance`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to just do

`UIPickerView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

put this in your AppDelegate and you are ready to go!

Comment: No, he was asking about a pickerView inside a UIWebView. Like choosing dates in Safari.

Comment: that works the same. I had same exact issue and this fixed it for me